# Statistical Signifance Test for discrete data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I'm fairly new to statistics and want to perform a statistical analysis (calculation of p value)
for data I collected, but I'm unsure if I'm doing it correctly and would like some feedback/help.

I have 180 ratings from 1 to 10 for two categories, so 90 ratings per category.
This is the distribution of answers for the categories:

[image: Barchart for ratings of categories A and B]

My goal is to prove that these datapoints result from the same underlying distribution, i.e.,
there is no statistical significant difference.
But I'm not sure what statistical test I should use, since there seem to be a lot of conditions and caveats.
The datapoints don't follow a normal distribution, so I should use a non parametric test.
My data is numerical and discrete, which also excludes a lot of options.
I tried the chisquare test but it results in NaN for the scipy.stats.chisquare method, since the values 1 and 10 have a frequency of 0. I could just exclude 1 and 10, but I don't know if thats valid. The output I get is:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=9.400411679823446, pvalue=0.22517169474250875)
```

Another test I tried is the Mann Whitney U test, which gave me the following result:

```
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=4061.5, pvalue=0.9742929619325416)
```

Can I use the latter approach? Did I make any mistake so far?

Comment: Assuming the ratings are unpaired, this is a textbook context for applying a chi-squared test.  The categories with low counts (2 and 9) won't really be a problem, despite the standard rules of thumb stating so.  If the ratings are paired, other standard choices are available that are likely much more powerful than any unpaired test.

Comment: Since *Confidence* was measured on response from 1 to 10, you likely want to treat this variable as ordinal in nature (ordered categorical).  In this case, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test you used is a likely candidate to compare the two groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are treating the responses for *Confidence* as ordinal categories, your bar plot of counts for *Confidence* responses for each *Group* suggests that there is no systematic difference in the central tendency of the responses for the groups.

To test this, you might use a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test, which assesses the probability that a response from *Group A* is greater than a response from *Group B*.

You could also compare median responses from the *Groups* with Mood's median test or another test of medians.

If you wanted to take a bit of a leap of faith and compare the mean responses --- you could assume that the responses are interval in nature and that the marginal distribution of the responses are normal in distribution --- and use a *t* test.

You might be a little careful with your conclusions. You can't ***prove*** that these samples come from the same distribution.  But it looks like you don't have good evidence that they come from different distributions (based on the tests described).

Below is the approximate data extracted from the plot, and a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test, in R.

The *vda()* function then calculates the probability that an observation from *A* will be greater than an observation from *B*.  The result, close to 0.5, suggests that neither group is very likely to have observations greater than the other group.

```
if(!require(tidyr)){install.packages("tidyr")}

Data = read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, text="

Group Confidence Count
A 1   0
A 2   2
A 3   8
A 4   8
A 5   8
A 6  20
A 7  24
A 8  17
A 9   3
A 10  0
B 1   0
B 2   2
B 3   7
B 4   9
B 5   9
B 6  14
B 7  34
B 8  11
B 9   4
B 10  0
")

library(tidyr)

Long = uncount(Data, Count)

rownames(Long) = seq(1:nrow(Long))

Long

library(FSA)

Summarize(Confidence ~ Group, data=Long)

wilcox.test(Confidence ~ Group, data=Long)

    ### W = 4038.5, p-value = 0.9743


library(rcompanion)

vda(Confidence ~ Group, data=Long, verbose=TRUE)

   ###            Statistic Value
   ### 1 Proportion Ya > Yb 0.406
   ### 2 Proportion Ya < Yb 0.409
   ### 3    Proportion ties 0.185
   ###  
   ### VDA 
   ### 0.499
```

Answer (score 4):

As an opening observation, you should never begin your statistical analysis with a goal of getting a particular result in your test --- rather than aiming to prove that the two sets of data come from the same distribution, your goal should merely be to inquire to see whether or not this is the case, with an *a priori* openness to the possibility that the underlying distributions may be different.

As to the method of testing, assuming your data values are not paired, it would be reasonable to use any well-performing two-sample test for sameness of distribution.  There are a number of these tests, including the [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), the [two-sample Kuiper test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test), the [two-sample Anderson Darling test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Non-parametric_k-sample_tests), or the [two-sample Pearson chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test).$^\dagger$

---

$^\dagger$ Note: The former tests are created for continuous distributions so you would need to determine the appropriate null distribution via simulation (e.g., using bootstrapping methods).  The latter test treats the variables as categorical, which loses some of the ordering structure, but it is appropriate for discrete distributions under broad circumstances.

Comment: I ruled the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test out because I read that it shouldn't be used with discrete data. Is that incorrect? The problem with the chi-square test is, that it can't handle  0's in the data (division by 0).

Comment: My understanding is that it is possible to adjust the test for a discrete distribution by simulating the null distribution instead of using the asymptotic KS distribution (e.g., via bootstrapping).  Not certain how accurate this is, so reasonable to avoid if you prefer.  I've edited the answer to note this.